# A question about pointwise convergence of bounded functions

Tags: real-analysis

I have a sequence $f_{n}$ of smooth, positive, bounded functions on $\mathbb{R}$, converging in $L^{1}\cap L^{2}$ (and hence pointwise a.e.) to a continuous, bounded function $f$. Is it possible to prove that $f_{n}$ is uniformly bounded, i.e. there is a constant $C$ such that $|f_{n}(x)|\leq C$ for all x (at least for large $n$)? Thank you very much!

Comment: No. More important: The "hence" in your statement is wrong. Convergence in $L^1\cap L^2$ does _not_ imply convergence almost everywhere.

Comment: Consider 
$$ f_n(x) = n \exp\left[-n^{20}(x-n)^{2}\right] $$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio You decided to shift the placement of your peak with $n$, perhaps just to have the added bonus of “converging everywhere” in addition to $L^1 \cap L^2$?

Comment: @Michael : exactly.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio thanks for the nice counterexample!

Comment: @David C. Ullrich Thank you, I meant I have strong convergence in the $L^{1}$ and in the $L^{2}$ norm. But couldn't I equip $L^{1}\cap L^{2}$ with the norm $\|f\|_{L^{1}\cap L^{2}}=\|f\|_{L^{1}}+\|f\|_{L^{2}}$ to make it a Banach space?

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought you meant. Yes, you can make $L^1\cap L^2$ a Banach space that way. I'm missing your point - none of this changes the fact that convergence in that norm (or in those norms) does _not_ imply convergence almost everywhere.

Comment: You're right I missed the "up to subsequence" part for the pointwise convergence. Thank you.